# How to create different access levels in aws cognito?

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I have a working web app developed using aws web services including api gateway, lambda and dynamo db. I used cognito user pool to authenticate the users. But I failed to find a way to achieve following scenario

- I want the users to select a package from 3 different packages and based on the package selected I want to limit the number of api calls a user can make. After reading number of articles, tutorials and docs etc. Could not find a proper way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this using cognito user [groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-user-groups.html). Create 3 groups in your user pool for your 3 different package users. Next go to your identity pool and click on edit. Now under Authentication providers select your user pool and ensure "Choose role from token" is selected like this. 
[image]

You can now create 3 different roles for your 3 different groups and attach whatever policy you want. 
After this, just put users in groups according to what plans they select. When they log in they will only have the rights that were provided to them by the role attached to their group. 
You can read more about groups [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cognito-groups-and-fine-grained-role-based-access-control-2/).